# Insertar imagen de fondo en un navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift

Estoy haciendo un **app** en la cual, un determinado `View Controller` tiene una imagen de fondo la cual coloco mediante un **`UIImageView`**.

El problema que tengo es que el top del **`UIImageView`** llega hasta el `bottom` de la `NavigationBar`, por lo cual, ésta ultima es fácil de distinguir.

Lo que necesito hacer, es si la imagen del `imageView` puede estar continuada en el `navigationBar`, es decir que la imagen cubra desde lo mas bajo hasta lo mas alto de la pantalla, sin interrupción alguna.

Comment: Ponle al navigation bar transparencia pera que la imagen se vea o de lo contrario oculta el navigation bar